# Question dissection or how can I improve this question

Tags: support, specific-question

I posted this question ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813726/recyclerview-not-updating-while-dialogframent-open-on-orientation-change)) a few days ago but it has received little attention and even got downvoted once for no apparent reason. I would like to know how can I improve so that it receives more attention and helps the SO volunteers to better help me solve my problem. Also I would like to know why might be that it got downvoted.

Comment: Not my field of expertise, but: I've found SO readers really *really* like questions with a bit of code. Even (sigh) when explicitly asked for, say, a description of an algorithm. Are you sure your question cannot be enhanced with a short snippet?

Comment: The thing is I don't know part to put that is relevant for the question. It might occur that I post a snippet of code that ends up being (not knowing it) not relevant for the problem because that part of the code might be innocuous.

Comment: @RadLexus Added some code that maybe could help, though I don't get my hopes up.

Comment: It might be good to add a picture of the behavior you're describing. (And maybe remove some of the unnecessary words.) Many people don't have the patience to read that much.

Comment: @Laurel Tried to trim it a bit. Don't know what else to remove.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few things:

1. Keep the title easy to understand(which is good in your [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813726/recyclerview-not-refreshing-after-rotating-the-device-with-an-open-dialogfragmen))
2. Description of the question should be brief - describe just the problem

   Try to keep the descriptions to the point. You don't have to explain your whole use case. Just keep whatever is required in the question. (I think lots of details are unnecessary in your question. Eg : The process to be followed)
3. Try to keep the whole question short so that its easier for any one to view and get an idea of what could be the problem & suggest tips in comments(if not an answer)
4. Keep your code short and to the point.

   (you may put up the required part of code only or just tidy up the existing one as it has too many spaces in it)
5. Add appropriate tags to the question (which I think you have covered)
6. Add a snapshot of final output(if possible) so that is easier to visualize what you want.

Even after following all of these, if you don't get required solution or suggestion(this usually happens if your question is very specific or not salvageable**) you may put it up with a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

**If your question is flagged not salvageable, then try to fix it or ask other users how you could improve it.

Comment: If the question isn't salvageable, putting up a bounty is the worst thing you can do.

Comment: "if you don't get required solution" --> this happens when the question is not salvageable or very specific!

Comment: I read your last sentence as `If your question is flagged not salvageable, then ... put it up for a bounty`

Comment: @Laurel the "..." has the stuff that's to be done before putting up a bounty.

Comment: I'm just saying the wording is potentially ambiguous. You may want to reword that to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Laurel I think its fixed.

Comment: You also had a period killing the markdown. Yes, it's better now.

Answer (score -1):

I get bad feelings when I look at your linked question, but I couldn't explain *why* at first. All of the necessary pieces are there, but I think that you need to assemble them a bit better.

Let me step through it:

### Title

Your title is ok, but it could be improved. Currently, it's a bit hard to read because it's so dense (do you need all of that?). It's also not a full, grammatical sentence.

I might change the title to something like:

> DialogFragment doesn't reflect deleted rows in database when device is rotated

(Note that I have no clue if this accurately describes your problem. You need to revise all this stuff for technical accuracy.)

The title is the first thing that people see. Make it as inviting as possible.

### Opening

I think you need to piece together the problem better.

I would suggest something like:

> I'm making an app that interacts with a database. It has a RecyclerView where rows can be created, updated, or deleted.
>
> It's almost working, but when I rotate the device, and delete a row, it doesn't show the changes in the DialogFragment, but the row is removed from the database.
>
> When I do the same thing, but create a new row, everything works and it shows that there is a new row in the RecyclerView.

I would then outline what you have tried, and how it didn't work. You might also consider including a picture, if it helps describe the problem.

### Code

I can't say too much about your code, but it's long (not to mention that you're linking to MORE code).

I actually edited your code to remove some of the unnecessary blank lines. I also split up several long lines so that it doesn't require horizontal scrolling.

You are also using a style of bracketing that takes up more lines:

```
public void method()
{
```

While both styles are equally valid, you can give the illusion of shorter code by using the other style:

```
public void method(){
```

And lastly, you should make sure that people can actually copy paste run your code with as little effort as possible.

Comment: I'll use your suggestions to modify the question post. Thank you.